# Upgraded Ubuntu server 18.04 to 20.04 switched to desktop with power managment

Tags: server, upgrade, power-management

I have upgraded a Ubuntu server 18.04 to 20.04 in terminal using do-release-upgrade. Everything when fine. After a while, after the seemingly successful upgrade to 20.04, the server became unresponsive, timeout from ssh. Rebooted, and same scenario again after a little while (about 2hr?). Skimming through logs I found in this syslog:

```
Nov 13 15:11:32 gattaca NetworkManager[1543]: <info>  [1605298292.4734] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Nov 13 15:11:32 gattaca NetworkManager[1543]: <info>  [1605298292.4738] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Nov 13 15:11:32 gattaca gnome-shell[2995]: Screen lock is locked down, not locking
Nov 13 15:11:32 gattaca systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Nov 13 15:11:32 gattaca systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Nov 13 15:11:32 gattaca systemd-sleep[4841]: Suspending system...
```

It seems there are some power managment going on. Could it have been turned into a Ubuntu Desktop release? How can I disable power managment? Or better can I revert back to Server release?

thanks for your help!

Philippe